# Question about Helmholtz's paper "ON THE CONSERVATION OF FORCE"

Tags: thermodynamics, forces, classical-mechanics, energy-conservation

***Below follows the exact extract from Helmholtz's paper "On the conservation of force".***

Let us now imagine, instead of the system $A$, a single material
point $a$, it follows from what has been just proved,
that the
direction and magnitude of the force exerted by $a$ upon $m$ is only
affected by the position which $m$ occupies with regard to $a$. But
the only circumstance, as regards position, that can affect the
action between the two points is the distance $ma$; the law,
therefore, in this case would require to be so modified, that the
direction and magnitude of the force must be functions of the
said distance, which we shall name $r$. Let us suppose the co
ordinates referred to any system of axes whatever whose origin
lies in $a$, we have then
$$md(q^2)=2Xdx+2Ydy+2Zdz=0 \tag{3}$$
as often as $$d(r^2)=2xdx+2ydy+2zdz=0$$
that is, as often as
 $$dz=-\frac{xdx+ydy}{z}$$
setting this value in equation (3), we obtain
$$(X-\frac{x}{z}Z)dx+(Y-\frac{y}{z}Z)dy=0$$
for any values whatever of $dx$ and $dy$ ; hence also singly

$$X=\frac{x}{z}Z\tag{1}$$  $$Y=\frac{y}{z}Z\tag{2}$$
that is to say, the resultant must be directed towards the origin
of coordinates, or towards the point $a$.

Hence in systems to which the principle of the conservation
of force can be applied, in all its generality, the elementary forces
of the material points must be central forces.

***My question is about the equation (1) and (2). In which way these formulas reveal that the resultant must be directed towards the origin of coordinates?***

The paper can be find here:

https://play.google.com/books/reader?id=C1i4AAAAIAAJ&hl=en&pg=GBS.PA120